# Authenticating python application against Azure Active Directory interactively with a device code

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory

```
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AADTokenCredentials
import adal, uuid, time

authority_host_uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com"
tenant_id = "..."
client_id = "..."
authority_uri = authority_host_uri + '/' + tenant_id
resource_uri = "https://storage.azure.com/"
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_uri, api_version=None)
code = context.acquire_user_code(resource_uri, client_id)
print(code['message'])

mgmt_token = context.acquire_token_with_device_code(resource_uri, code, client_id)
credentials = AADTokenCredentials(mgmt_token, client_id)
```

Trying get access to Azure AD interactively with a device code. Anyway, there is no windows pop-up but console correctly output the code "To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code EUDR3PTL6 to authenticate."

Opening the url and enter the code, it output the new error "AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application."

How could I get a interactively pop-up window to input device code or user credential to get the token from Azure AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected result for **Device code flow**, you need to use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code EUDR3PTL6 to authenticate.

> For applications running on devices which don't have a web browser,
>   it's possible to acquire a token through the device code mechanism,
>   which provides the user with a URL and a code. The user goes to a web
>   browser on another device, enters the code and signs-in, and then
>   Azure AD returns back a token to the browser-less device.

You got an AADSTS500113 error because you din't have an reply address registered for your application.
You need to add a platform and provide a redirect url in azure portal. The redirect url is not used for Device code flow, but it is needed.

[image]

Reference:

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Acquire-tokens

Comment: Is any other interactively options here to authenticate via AD instead of device code. Open an extra browser is not really user friendly.

Comment: @Jonas Based on the document, you can also use `Authorization Code Flow`. But I didn't try it before, you can have a try. https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Acquire-tokens#public-client-applications